# Python function callback and if issue

Tags: python

I just ended to write my Python code for an assignment but I'm a bit stuck on a last point, could you help me to figure out why ?

Here is my code :

```
import random

def get_rand_int(arg1, arg2):

    rand = random.randint(arg1, arg2)
    if float(rand) == float(arg1):
        return None
    elif float(rand) == float(arg2):
        return None
    else:
        return rand 

def print_random():
    try :
        prompt = int(input("Please enter an integer greater than 0:"))
        assert(prompt > 0)

    except:
        print("Invalid input: You must input an integer greater than 0 for your input.")

    rand = get_rand_int(0, prompt)

    if rand > 0: 
        print( "Your random number is ",rand)
    elif rand is None:
        print( " Please Launch the program again")
```

The second function call the first one to generate a random number according to the user prompt. Everything work except in the case that the generate random number is the same than one of the argument, my program should print " Please launch the program again". However its not working and nothing happen in this situation ( nothing is printed ) 
Do you have any idea to how make properly work this last if loop?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you casting the numbers to float, if everything is integers?

Comment: Well that's great answer, will correct it indeed

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: I always get output, though half of the time it's an error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

Comment: Was an error, I'm just a beginner with Python ! I corrected it

Comment: I make run the program on Jupyter if that can help

Comment: But do you get any errors for particular inputs, such as `1`? You suggest in your question you don't see *any* output at all.

Comment: No the program is working as it should except in one case, when the arg1 or arg2 are equal to the generate random number. Indeed, in this case it does not print the last "Please launch again the program" of the last elif

Comment: In that case, it should show an error message. If you don't see an error message, that means you've somehow set up your notebook to suppress error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
import random
def get_rand_int(arg1, arg2):

    rand = random.randint(arg1, arg2)
    #print("Test", rand)
    if rand == arg1:
        return None
    elif rand == arg2:
        return None
    else:
        return rand 

def print_random():
    try :
        prompt = int(input("Please enter an integer greater than 0:"))
        assert(prompt > 0)

    except:
        print("Invalid input: You must input an integer greater than 0 for your input.")

    rand = get_rand_int(0, prompt)

    if rand != None: 
        print( "Your random number is ",rand)
    else:
        print( " Please Launch the program again")

print_random()
```

More Optimal Solution:

```
import random
def get_rand_int(arg1, arg2):
    rand = random.randint(arg1, arg2)
    if rand != arg1 or rand != arg2:
        return rand
    return None

def print_random():
    try :
        prompt = int(input("Please enter an integer greater than 0:"))
        assert(prompt > 0)

    except:
        print("Invalid input: You must input an integer greater than 0 for your input.")

    rand = get_rand_int(0, prompt)

    if rand != None: 
        print( "Your random number is ",rand)
    else:
        print( " Please Launch the program again")

print_random()
```

Output:

```
Please enter an integer greater than 0:7                                                                                                                                                                                            
Your random number is  2
```

Another Output:

```
Please enter an integer greater than 0:0                                                                              
Invalid input: You must input an integer greater than 0 for your input.                                               
Please Launch the program again
```

Comment: Note that your solutions still have a problem when a non-integer is input, such as `a` or `1.23`.

Comment: @ArthurGUYART If this answer helps you Please accept by tick (✓) mark so that other people will also get help from this.